# WordPress Borlabs Cookies: Modifiy "previewHTML" using filters

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins

I am using the Borlabs Cookie plugin for WordPress and i am trying to add filters to modify the preview html for content blocking as described here: https://borlabs.io/kb/action-filter-hooks/#ch_9. However, the return value does not seem to be used at all and just gets replaced with the default html.

This is my current code in my `functions.php`:

```
add_filter('borlabsCookie/contentBlocker/modify/content/vimeo', function ($content) {
    $contentBlockerData = BorlabsCookieHelper()->getContentBlockerData('vimeo');

    // example editing of previewHTML
    $contentBlockerData['previewHTML'] = '';

    // debug
    echo 'DEBUG';

    return $contentBlockerData['previewHTML'];
});
```

"Debug" gets printed so at this point the preview html should be empty, but in the frontend it still produces the default content blocker preview html:

```
<div class="BorlabsCookie">
    <div class="_brlbs-content-blocker">
        <div class="_brlbs-embed _brlbs-video-vimeo">
...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone else have this problem? I know that this can easily be done in the admin area of the plugin but I would still like to be able to use filter hooks for this issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The `return $contentBlockerData['previewHTML']` always will return an empty string. The string `$contentBlockerData['previewHTML'] = '';` right above the `return` sets the value to an empty string and that value is returned. I can guess this is not what you intended to achieve?

Comment: Did you try without this `$contentBlockerData['previewHTML'] = '';`

Comment: This is in fact what i want to achieve. The problem is whatever value I set, it will not get used in the frontend. I will edit the question to make this more clear, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution! Was very easy actually.

For anyone interested: The plugin has a standard filter with a priority of 100. So in order to apply a custom filter **after** the default filter, a priority greater than 100 is needed:

```
add_filter('borlabsCookie/contentBlocker/modify/content/vimeo', function ($content) {
    ...
}, 1000, 1);
```